# LEDs and the correct pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, acronyms

The [LED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode) is quickly becoming a standard light source alternative to incandescent lights, when speaking to others, I have always pronounced any reference to LED as the acronym "L E D", but increasingly I have heard others refer to LED as "lead".

Staff at large box stores often use the "lead" reference, and several of my family have also used the word "lead" in reference to LED.

What I find interesting is that LED's have been around since the 1960's and were always referred to as an acronym. Anyone who studied electrical engineering in school would not use "lead" in a sentence.

Still times have changed and "lead" is increasingly being used.

Is it correct to use the word "lead" to refer to LED?

Comment: It's no more incorrect than fluro instead of fluorescent lighting. (Proper light shop) attendants insist calling the light bulb a lamp. Don't expect anyone in a hardware store or even a common light store to understand anything about light spectrums and other light quality related matters. Reason I mention this is that the (lowest) common denominator usually becomes the norm. I'm confused if you want the norm or correctness. Not that I've been raised with a golden spoon or such. LED (lead) is common term now but, they're not buying it because it's not strong..unless you go a real light store $

Comment: I've been asked is "lead" was correct, and sometimes I correct people not to use "lead". With that said, I may incorrect in doing so.

Comment: You tell us what standard for "correctness" you wish to apply, and we may be able to tell you whether or not it is correct. _There is no universal or authoritative standard for what is "correct" in English_.

Comment: Thanks for speeling it out @Colin Fine. 2+2=5 is incorrect but, there's no clear-cut correctness with regard to popular terminology. A long time ago the radio was called a wireless. Were they incorrect?

Comment: Is the concern confusing it with [leads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead_(electronics)) or [lead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead)? I've not heard this and I don't see anything in your post to give it away...

Comment: @JoeWreschnig people aren't confusing LED with another meaning. So I don't think that needs to be clarified.

Comment: So based upon the comments, "lead" is commonly used and nothing wrong with using "lead" to refer to LED. That is basically the same of "lead" being correct. I just looking for confirmation that it's not incorrect. An example, might be that "leed" is incorrect.

Comment: *What I find interesting is that LED's have been
around since the 1960's and were always referred
to as an acronym.* An acronym is an abbreviation/initialism that's pronounced, like NASA but not the BBC. Anyway, I think saying either "L. E. D." or "led" is fine.

Comment: @Chris Since I started doing theatre in the 60s, stage electricians and designers have maintained these distinctions: the "lamp" (the top of which is enclosed by a glass "bulb") is screwed or plugged into an "instrument", and "light" is the bright stuff that comes out the front. They're pretty strict about it, because it's a pain making extra trips up and down a thirty-foot A-frame ladder.

Comment: @Hugo: I think that the original usage of the word _acronym_ was confined to words formed, of course, from the initial letters of a phrase, but actually accepted as lower-case entries in dictionaries (there aren't that many) such as _scuba_, _radar_, and _laser_. Probably the many items such as NASA and ISA where the capitalisation remains but the string is pronounced as a normal word would now be accepted as acronyms by most authorities. BBC is an _initialism_; I'm not sure if NASA would also be considered as a member of this set.

Comment: I wonder how many people who pronounce it *lead* are old enough to remember *[Led zepplin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Led_Zeppelin)*, which was definitely **not** pronounced *El-ee-dee Zeppelin*

Comment: I've always known them as /ɛll iː diːz/.

Comment: @Matt I always understood that Led Zeppelin took their name from a dismissive  comment an older person made that their act "would go down like lead zeppelin". Since they were formed in 1968 and the first patent for a visible-spectrum LED was issued in 1962 (aren't search engines great?) I don't think that LEDs had anything to do with their choice of name. Of course there is also the word "led" as in "led down a blind alley".

Comment: I heard only the "lead" pronunciation when becoming aware of them in the 1970s.
Why would EEs disdain the pronunciation? Do EEs say L-A-S-E-R?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm from Poland where I studied electronics and I say *LED* as in *lead*, but we don't have any other word(s) to mix it up with, whereas you have *lead* and *led* in English. I have noticed people pronounced it as acronym only.

Answer (score 24):

Setting aside the question of "correct" pronunciation, we can look at actual usage and draw some conclusions. Although this is a question about pronunciation, we are lucky in that we can look at written usage to get clues about pronunciation: if someone writes "an LED" we can assume they would have used the spelling pronunciation, and if they write "a LED" we can assume they would have used the word pronunciation.

A quick perusal at Google Ngrams shows that "an LED" is more commonly used, so the spelling pronunciation’s correctness is not in question. However, we can look at how common do we find  "a LED", indicating a likely use of the word pronunciation

[image: Google ngram for "an LED" vs "a LED"]

We see that since the 1980s, when the term came into wide use, about 20% of usages have held pretty steadily with the word pronunciation.

What conclusions can we draw from this? Well, not a lot. The spelling pronunciation is definitely preferred, but the word pronunciation is not unknown. It doesn't seem to be going away, so I would say it has established itself as a valid, though less common, variant.

Comment: I didn't know you could put formulae in Google nGrams!  Nice trick.  :-)

Comment: One thing to factor in, though: Some style prescriptions insist either that the indefinite article before an abbreviation/acronym must agree with the pronunciation of the first letter or that of the word, and the author has but to comply.

Comment: @Pitarou Click on the 'Help' link -- there's plenty interesting in there.

Comment: @Kris, you mean to say that some style guide somewhere would insist on "an NASA project"?

Comment: @nohat I would certainly not be surprised. Just note that style guides do not make concrete statements as your example is. No style guide will tell if NASA is pronounced *en-eh-ess-eh* or *Nahsah*.

Comment: @nohat I wonder just how accurate your test is. Many of your "a LED" hits may be false positives like "closed its series A led by a new" or "flasher has an integrated 2 A LED driver".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Google Ngrams are case sensitive, so these matches are only for cases where the word is spelled "LED" preceded by a lowercase "a" or "an"

Answer (score 6):

As founder and editor of LEDs Magazine, I'd like to offer the following: the most common usage is to pronounce the letters L E D and to add a letter s for the plural, in the same way as one would write or pronounce TVs. Our publication would always write "an LED." However, it's also relatively common to pronounce "led" to rhyme with "dead." I believe the Dictionary extract quoted above is incorrect, since it should never be correct usage to write the letters in lower case. LED or L.E.D. only.

Comment: Do you ever have articles on RADAR?

Answer (score 5):

The Oxford English Dictionary has *LED* pronounced /ɛliːˈdiː/ ... Also the alternate spelling *l.e.d.* ... they list a third alternate spelling *led* with pronunciation /lɛd/ .

**added for Tim**

The OED does not try to tell us what is "correct usage" but only what they find actually used.  Most of their examples are *LED* but they do have these as well:

1975   *Hi-Fi Answers Feb. 78/2*   The light pulses from the led are picked up by a photo-conductive cell and applied to the filter.

1976   *Pract. Electronics Oct. 810 (caption)*    Block diagram of the system using two separate l.e.d. displays.

1982   *What's New in Computing Nov. 19/2*   The logger can be programmed to these levels, indicating on a led display which channel is giving a fault condition signal.

Answer (score 2):

In speech, the context also determines how it is pronounced.

An  /ˌel iː ˈdiː/ TV compared to an LCD TV;
but
/led/ lights compared to a neon lights.

LED (yourdictionary.com)
lead. ☆. noun. a semiconductor diode that emits light when voltage is applied: used in electric lighting, alphanumeric displays, as on digital watches, etc.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that I have noticed here is a lot of people referring to LED as an acronym and then saying that as such it should be pronounced letter by letter. Acronym and initialism is not the same. An acronym should always be pronounced as a word (NASA, FIFA, UNESCO, NATO), while an initialism is always pronounced letter by letter (FBI, CIA, FIA). Now wether LED is an acronym or an initialism I don't know, but one thing is for sure: saying that LED is an acronym and should be pronounced L-E-D is incorrect, it's either one or the other.

Although the question is only interested in the english pronounciation I think in this situation it could be benefitial to look at other languages too. For example, I am Hungarian and in my language the only pronouncation you hear is as an acronym (like 'lead'). Here in Hungary no one uses the letter by letter pronounciation. This could prove that really both are correct, one is just more popular than the other in some countries, and the other dominates in other countries.

Answer (score 0):

In UK science and engineering both are common.  I would say that "L E D" is more widely used among electronics types, while old mechanical engineers go for pronouncing it as "led".  As there are now some brand names ([Lumileds](http://www.philipslumileds.com/)) that clearly pronounce (and even capitalise) it as a word, this form seems to be on the increase.

Although there are homophones, they are not easily confused in context - although lead (Pb) is a noun, "a lead" makes sense only in a limited range of contexts (pencils, weights for some specific purposes), while a light emitting diode is always going to have some sort of electrical/lighting context.

Answer (score -3):

In Australia, among technical folks (Engineers and Technicians) since the 1970's the pronunciation was as in the word 'led'. Recently in lighting commercials for the great unwashed, the pronunciation is to pronounce each letter individually.

I have also noted that amongst the technically uneducated, the preferred pronunciation is L E D.

I was taught in high school, that an acronym should be pronounced depending on its spelling, hence UNICEF instead of U N I C E F, UNESCO instead of U N E S C O, NASA instead of N A S A, ADFA (Australian Defence Force Academy) instead of A D F A; i.e. the rule is if there are vowels between consonants, the acronym should be pronounced as a word.

Pronouncing L.E.D as 'led', means selecting a consistent form of pronunciation, and if a person pronounces each letter separately as in L E D, they must be consistent and say N A S A not NASA.

Comment: Since when has anything in English pronunciation ever been consistent?

Comment: *"I have also noted that amongst the technically uneducated, the preferred pronunciation is L E D."* I won't bore you with qualifications. In common with thousands of others, I pronounce it "el-ee-dee." *Pronouncing L.E.D as 'led', means selecting a consistent form of pronunciation* and why would pronouncing it "el-ee-dee" be inconsistent? I suggest you are less subjective in your answers..